# replace coordinates in string with derived string javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I'm attempting to take a text/string and replace all coordinates in the string with alternate values.

For example:

```
This coord is [80,20] and [30,25]
```

should become:

```
This coord is <a href='location?x=80&y=20'>[80,20]</a> and <a href='location?x=30&y=25'>[30,25]</a>
```

basically, making coordinates in the text clickable direction links.

I already have my regex expression:

```
/\[\-{0,1}[0-9]{1,}\,\-{0,1}[0-9]{1,}\]/
```

I've tested it, and it will select what i'm looking for, but i'm not fluent with the javascript side of replacing substrings with regex, and taking the results of the regex, as part of the replacing string.

Any pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: str = str.replace("80","30").replace("20","25") ;)

Comment: I'm not replacing 80 with 30, i'm replacing the whole string "This coord is [80,20] with [30,20] 

i'm editing to take out 'with' so its less confusing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capture the coordinates with `()`, and then refer to them in the replacement as `$1`, `$2`, etc. `$&` refers to the match of the whole regexp.

```js
var string = 'This coord is [80,20] and [30,25]';
var newString = string.replace(/\[(-?\d+),(-?\d+)\]/g, "<a href='location?x=$1&y=$2'>$&</a>");
alert(newString);
```

Note that `{0,1}` can be simplified to `?`, and `{1,}` is equivalent to `+`. There's also no need to escape `=` or `,` in the regexp, and `\d` matches digits.

Comment: This was a simple answer! I was storing the regex in a RegExp constructor that was screwing with the replacement (not putting in the grouping, but rather printing the actual '$1')

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this

```
s.replace(
  /\[(\-{0,1}[0-9]{1,})\,(\-{0,1}[0-9]{1,})\]/g, 
  function(match, x, y, offset, str) {
    return  "<a href=\"location?x=" + x +
            "&y=" + y +
            "\">" + "["+x+","+y+"]" + "</a>";
  }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

### Quick Answer:

```
var coordPattern = /\[\s*\+?(-?)\s*0*(\d*\.?\d+)\s*,\s*\+?(-?)\s*0*(\d*\.?\d+)\s*\]/g;
var inputString = "This coord is [80,20] and [30,25]";
var outputString = inputString.replace(coordPattern, "<a href='location?x=$1$2&y=$3$4'>[$1$2,$3$4]</a>");
```

---

If you don't care about spaces

```
var coordPattern = /\[\+?(-?)0*(\d*\.?\d+),\+?(-?)0*(\d*\.?\d+)\]/g;
```

---

If you don't care about preceding plus or minus signs

```
var coordPattern = /\[\s*()\s*0*(\d*\.?\d+)\s*,\s*()\s*0*(\d*\.?\d+)\s*\]/g;
```

---

If you don't care decimals

```
var coordPattern = /\[\s*\+?(-?)\s*0*(\d+)\s*,\s*\+?(-?)\s*0*(\d+)\s*\]/g;
```

---

If you care about preceding zeros

```
var coordPattern = /\[\s*\+?(-?)\s*(\d*\.?\d+)\s*,\s*\+?(-?)\s*(\d*\.?\d+)\s*\]/g;
```

---

If you want it all!...Wealth. Women. And one more thing...

```
var coordPattern = /\[\s*\+?(-?)\s*0*(\d*\.?\d+)\s*,\s*\+?(-?)\s*0*(\d*\.?\d+)\s*\]/g;
```

---

### Test code

```js
var coordPattern = /\[\s*\+?(-?)\s*0*(\d*\.?\d+)\s*,\s*\+?(-?)\s*0*(\d*\.?\d+)\s*\]/g; // If you want it all!...Wealth. Women. And one more thing...
var testStrings = [
    "This coord is [80,20] and [30,25]",
    "This coord is [80 ,20] and [30, 25]",
    "This coord is [ 80,20] and [30,25 ]",
    "This coord is [-80,20] and [+30,25]",
    "This coord is [1.23,20] and [30,4.56]",
    "This coord is [-.123,20] and [+0.456,25]"
];

var expectedAnswers = [
    "This coord is <a href='location?x=80&y=20'>[80,20]</a> and <a href='location?x=30&y=25'>[30,25]</a>",
    "This coord is <a href='location?x=80&y=20'>[80,20]</a> and <a href='location?x=30&y=25'>[30,25]</a>",
    "This coord is <a href='location?x=80&y=20'>[80,20]</a> and <a href='location?x=30&y=25'>[30,25]</a>",
    "This coord is <a href='location?x=-80&y=20'>[-80,20]</a> and <a href='location?x=30&y=25'>[30,25]</a>",
    "This coord is <a href='location?x=1.23&y=20'>[1.23,20]</a> and <a href='location?x=30&y=4.56'>[30,4.56]</a>",
    "This coord is <a href='location?x=-.123&y=20'>[-.123,20]</a> and <a href='location?x=.456&y=25'>[.456,25]</a>"
];

for(var i = 0; i < testStrings.length; ++i){
    var inputString = testStrings[i];
    var expectedString = expectedAnswers[i];
    var outputString = inputString.replace(coordPattern, "<a href='location?x=$1$2&y=$3$4'>[$1$2,$3$4]</a>");

    jQuery('body').append(
      jQuery('<span>').append([
        '--test-passed=' + (outputString === expectedString),
        '--input="' +  inputString + '"',
        '--output=', outputString
        ].join('')
      ),
      jQuery('<br/>')
    );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```